# Anyone using MDL v2?

Tags: material-design-lite

I am already using es6 and sass so I think this would be a good fit.

But there is no npm package and the root package is private.

I don't really understand how can I use it in my project, anyoyne can help?

Thanks

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-design-lite

Comment: ok it installed material-design-lite@1.2.1. Was looking for 2.0

Comment: V2.0 is still in development.  It is currently highly experimental and no support building or using it will be provided.

Comment: Well I could have been an early adopter. Thanks anyway will keep an eye on it.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up vendoring the project (git submodule). Then building it and referencing the .js and .scss parts needed for my project.

Glad to use it.